# How to pass this data in ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel, react-bootstrap

I am working with ReactJS and in a carousel design of Bootstrap, I found this line:

```
    <div class="tns-carousel-inner" data-carousel-options="{&quot;mode&quot;: &quot;gallery&quot;, &quot;responsive&quot;: {&quot;0&quot;:{&quot;nav&quot;:true, &quot;controls&quot;: false},&quot;992&quot;:{&quot;nav&quot;:false, &quot;controls&quot;: true}}}">
```

I am passing the value of "data-carousel-options" as it is in the above line but it is not working. However, it works fine in plain HTML. I am not sure how I can use this line in ReactJS.

Comment: If you're using react bootstrap, you should use its carousel component. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Comment: Also, have you tried passing it like so? `data-carousel-options='{"mode": "gallery", "responsive": {"0":{"nav":true, "controls": false},"992":{"nav":false, "controls": true}}}'`

Comment: I'm using this theme
https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=35287

I'm trying to implement the carousel at the top of the page. It works fine in plain html. But when I'm trying to add it in a page of my ReactJS application, the carousel is not showing anything.

Also, I have tried the portion you mentioned in your second comment. It also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was not passing the data. The data can be passed exactly in the same way as it is in the question. The problem was, the javascript file which is responsible to act on the provided data needs to be loaded in each page individually. As I was working with React app, I put all the external javascript files (e.g: bootstrap, custom theme js, etc.) in the index.html file inside the "script" tag. But it turns out that not all javascript files work correctly in that way. Sometimes, some javascript files need to be loaded each time the route is changed. So, I had to include the javascript file inside the componentDidMount() and now it works fine.

Here is the link of another question that I asked on how to include external javascript files in ReactJs:
[How to make external javascript file work in ReactJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827621/how-to-make-external-javascript-file-work-in-reactjs)