# How to make external javascript file work in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, my public.html file looks like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some_stylesheet_file.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="function.js"></script>
</body>
```

All the components of the project load inside the "root" div.
The "function.js" file is an external javascript file from a theme.

In one of the React components, I have an input field:

```
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" />
```

Now, inside "componentDidMount()" of that component, if I write

```
console.log(document.getElementByID("userName"))
```

it shows the "userName" field correctly in the console. But if I do the same thing in the "function.js" file, the output is null, which indicates the external javascript file is not working properly. I am not sure how to make the external javascript file work so that I can use the properties of the theme. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the DOM method to load external JS in our ReactJS app.

For example, `https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js` is an external JS library provided by mesibo, we load it as following

```
const externalJS = "https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js";
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = externalJS;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Where to add this portion? Should I add this inside the React component?

Comment: We put it in index.html so that is available to all the components.

Comment: index.html is an html file. How can we write javascript there?
Would you please explain exactly where should I add this portion and how I can integrate it to the index.html file?

Comment: use <script></script> tags in <head>

Comment: @JohnWink You could add inside `useEffect` for the component which needs it.

Comment: useEffect may also work. But I implemented the solution Mark showed and it works now @Badal Saibo